# Declare custom DNS name for Fargate using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am creating a C# CDK stack that deploys both a Fargate service and an Elastic Beanstalk service.

Both these services will have a custom domain pointing to them using a third party domain service (i.e. non AWS).

For elastic beanstalk, I can simply set the `CnamePrefix` below, and AWS will generate something like `http://beanstalk-dev.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/` which I can then point my custom domain to (after adding some listeners to the load balancer).

```cs
 var elasticBeanstalkEnv = new CfnEnvironment(this, "ElbsEnv", new CfnEnvironmentProps
            {
                EnvironmentName = "beanstalk-dev",
                ApplicationName =  appName,
                SolutionStackName = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v2.4.1 running .NET Core",
                OptionSettings = optionSettingProperties,
                VersionLabel = version.Ref,
                CnamePrefix = "beanstalk-dev", <--- This property
                Tier = new CfnEnvironment.TierProperty
                {
                    Name = "WebServer",
                    Type = "Standard"
                }
            });
```

I am also trying to do something similar with Fargate. But I can not find any settings like the one for elastic beanstalk.

Below is what I have so far, which will deploy a DNS name like `LB-71455902.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`

```cs
 var fargate = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "reportviewer-server",
                new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateServiceProps
                {
                    TaskImageOptions = new ApplicationLoadBalancedTaskImageOptions
                    {
                        Image = ContainerImage.FromRegistry("myImage",
                            new RepositoryImageProps { Credentials = mycreds})
                    },
                    PublicLoadBalancer = true,
                    LoadBalancerName = "LB",
                    ServiceName = "frontend",
                    RecordType = ApplicationLoadBalancedServiceRecordType.CNAME
                });


            fargate.LoadBalancer.AddListener("ecs-https-listener", new ApplicationListenerProps
            {
                SslPolicy = SslPolicy.RECOMMENDED,
                Protocol = ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
                Open = true,
                Port = 443,
                Certificates = new IListenerCertificate[]
                {
                    ListenerCertificate.FromArn(
                        "myArn")
                },
                DefaultTargetGroups = new IApplicationTargetGroup[]
                {
                    fargate.TargetGroup
                }
            });
```

How would I setup my stack to create a "static" DNS name that wont be different each time I create/destroy my stack?

Comment: `DomainName` for `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`?

Comment: @kichik I think for that you also need to have a `HostedZone` setup in Route 53 to set the `DomainZone` property as well. But our DNS Services are currently hosted elsewhere.

Comment: An Application Load Balancer always gets a DNS name. You don't need Route53 for that.

Comment: @MarkB yes, but if I destroy my stack and recreate it, a new DNS name will be assigned to it at the moment. E.g. first creation will be `LB-71455902.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`. Second creation will be `LB-84193823.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`. Which means my domain name will now be pointing to a DNS that no longer exists.

Comment: You have to update your DNS records every time you create a new load balancer. There's really no way around that.

Comment: Ah damn, thanks @MarkB. Was really hoping there was something like Elastic Beanstalk provides with the CName property.